# NO java, available on Redhat 7.9 linux server

Tags: java, redhat

I'm trying to install java on redhat 7.9 and I tried everything on the net to install it but to no avail ....it keeps giving this message :

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos
No package java-1.8.0-openjdk available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

when I tried to search for it using `sudo yum search openjdk` it gave the following:

```
sudo yum search openjdk
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos
=============================== Matched: openjdk ===============================
mssql-zulu-jre-11.x86_64 : Azul Systems Zulu JRE for SQL Server
mssql-zulu-jre-8.x86_64 : Azul Systems Zulu JRE for SQL Server
```

I'm running on the following :

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME=RHEL
```

Comment: You might want to ask at the Unix SE site.

Comment: You can install java without yum.

Comment: how can I do that ...please help ....since this is just a terminal with no GUI

Comment: check this URL for howto install OpenJDK `https://openjdk.java.net/install/` and the package archives here `https://jdk.java.net/archive/`